# AVFoundation I use setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration didn't work

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapture

I use `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` in my demo ,for take photos in loop (like scanner) without sound,
so i set fps to low Level

```
[device setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, 1)];
[device setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, 1)];
```

In my code, then do this

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
   fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
     NSLog(@"date");
}
```

for check is it work, I found it print 24 times in a second,not 1 times 1 second

PS: the device edition is iPhone 5C and iOS 8.12

Comment: make it CMTimeMake(1, 10) and then check what happened..?

Comment: nothing changed, the info was printed 24 times per second

Comment: Which settings are you using? are you sure that 1FPS is a compatible option?

Comment: Are you calling  [device unlockForConfiguration]; at the end?

Comment: yes, I called [device unlockForConfiguration]; and locked before i modified it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just met the same problem.You should take a look at the function explanation about setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration or setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration.
Apple says:

> On iOS, the receiver's activeVideoMinFrameDuration resets to its default value under the following conditions:
>   - The receiver's activeFormat changes
>   - The receiver's AVCaptureDeviceInput's session's sessionPreset changes
>   - The receiver's AVCaptureDeviceInput is added to a session

So, you should call setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration and setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration **after** changing activeFormat,sessionPreset and AVCaptureSession's addInput.

Comment: Another one thing that made you freak out about Apple's documentation... Why on the earth such an important condition is mentioned in function header and not in the Official Documentation?!?!?! The two sides of apple... a neverending story...

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT**

For those who are looking for an elegant Swifty solution, here is what I got from the latest official documentation

> The following code example illustrates how to select an iOS device’s highest possible frame rate:

```
func configureCameraForHighestFrameRate(device: AVCaptureDevice) {

 var bestFormat: AVCaptureDevice.Format?
 var bestFrameRateRange: AVFrameRateRange?

 for format in device.formats {
     for range in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges {
         if range.maxFrameRate > bestFrameRateRange?.maxFrameRate ?? 0 {
             bestFormat = format
             bestFrameRateRange = range
         }
     }
 }

 if let bestFormat = bestFormat, 
    let bestFrameRateRange = bestFrameRateRange {
     do {
         try device.lockForConfiguration()

         // Set the device's active format.
         device.activeFormat = bestFormat

         // Set the device's min/max frame duration.
         let duration = bestFrameRateRange.minFrameDuration
         device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = duration
         device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = duration

         device.unlockForConfiguration()
     } catch {
         // Handle error.
     }
 }
}
```

Reference: 
[Apple Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice)